# mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given

Tags: php, mysqli

```
if (phpversion() >= '4.3.0'){
    $string = mysqli_real_escape_string($string);
}else{
    $string = mysqli_escape_string($string);
}
```

All the documentation for `mysqli_real_escape_string` seems to indicate this is a valid bit of code, but I don't understand why I get this error:

> mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given

Comment: Are you sure you're reading the documentation for `mysqli_real_escape_string` rather than `mysql_real_escape_string`? Particularly as `mysqli` functions don't exist before PHP 5...

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) says it needs two parameters:

```
string mysqli_real_escape_string ( mysqli $link , string $escapestr )
```

The first one is a link for a mysqli instance, the second one is the string to escape.

Answer (score 3):

Following is the proper format to use it :

```
string mysqli_real_escape_string ( mysqli $link , string $escapestr )
```

first parameter is mysql connection link identifier, and second is string
For more details, you can visit this link : https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php.

Answer (score 3):

Let me just add an extra bit of information:
If you are using NetBeans, its documentation actually shows the mysqli_real_escape_string 
function like this:

```
mysqli_real_escape_string (PHP 5)
    Escapes special characters in a string for use in an SQL statement, taking into account the current charset of the connection

Parameters:

    string $escapestr
        'The string to be escaped.'

Returns:

    Type:
    string

Description:
    an escaped string.
```

This is wrong, though, as shown in the other answers. It requires both the $link and the $string.

Comment: Do you know how can I do it so netbeans autocomplete feature will show `mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $escapestr)` instead of `mysqli_real_escape_string($escapestr)`?

Comment: Close Netbeans. Go to: `<Netbeans Install Path>\php\phpstubs\phpruntime` and edit the file `mysqli.php`, press `CTRL`+`F` and search for `mysqli_real_escape_string`. Add the `$link`parameter before the `$escapestr`and in the commented part above, add `* @param mysqli $link` in the line before `* @param string $escapestr <p>`. Open Netbeans and test it.

Comment: Note: you might have to open the file in an editor with administrator rights, or copy it to desktop, edit it there and copy/replace it back in the original folder.

Comment: 4 years later, netbeans documentation still buggy.

Answer (score 2):

```
$con = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "your_password", "your_database_name");
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$empno = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $data->empno);//this will do your work
```

Answer (score 1):

mysqli_real_escape_string(**DBconnection**, __dat__a);
mysqli_real_escape_string needs the db connection variable